# Bootable USB isn't found in UEFI boot options and when trying to boot in Legacy it shows a GNU GRUB minimal bash screen

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, grub

I was using a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu (both version 20.04), I use a multiboot flash drive with Ventoy, that I use to test multiple ISOs and install quite a few of them.

After removing Ubuntu by following the instructions from multiple tutorials (deleting Ubuntu's partition and removing its folder from the EFI partition) my bootable drive does not work anymore, I'm currently unninstalling and reinstalling ventoy to see if it could have gotten corrupted in any way, but that feels unlikely. Thank you for any support given.

UPDATE: After reinstalling Ventoy, it booted up again, how is it, that by deleting a drive partition on the drive, together with a folder of the system included in another partition of the drive, affect a flash drive unrelated to it? It seems that something else caused the issue, but overall... Issue is fixed.

Comment: Bootable to *what OS*? How did you make it? We do not have clairvoyance turned on.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've corrected grammar and added the necessary information, I'm sorry for my previous lack of context, thank you for correcting me.